# AngularJs broadcast event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to broadcast angular event from javascript function i.e angular.injector(['ng', 'myModule']).get("mySharedService").prepForBroadcast('hello');
By using above line I can invoke prepForBroadcast() but I  can't catch event in  $scope.$on()

Note: I want to call  prepForBroadcast() method from javascript function.

```
    <!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- SPELLS -->
  <!-- load angular via CDN -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <style>
    .question{
        border:1px solid darkgray;
        padding:10px;
        margin-bottom:10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myModule">
        <div id="appID" ng-controller="ControllerZero">
            <input ng-model="message" >
        </div>

        <div ng-controller="ControllerOne">
            <input ng-model="message" >
        </div>

        <div ng-controller="ControllerTwo">
            <input ng-model="message" >
        </div>

        <my-component ng-model="message"></my-component>
    </div>

</body>
<script>
angular.injector(['ng','myModule']).get("mySharedService").prepForBroadcast('hello');
</script>
</html>
```

script.js file

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);
myModule.factory('mySharedService', function($rootScope) {
    var sharedService = {};

    sharedService.message = '';

    sharedService.prepForBroadcast = function(msg) {
        console.log('prepForBroadcast');
        this.message = msg;
        this.broadcastItem();
    };

    sharedService.broadcastItem = function() {
        console.log('broadcastItem');
        $rootScope.$broadcast('handleBroadcast');
    };

    return sharedService;
});

myModule.directive('myComponent', function(mySharedService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: function($scope, $attrs, mySharedService) {
            $scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function() {
                $scope.message = 'Directive: ' + mySharedService.message;
            });
        },
        replace: true,
        template: '<input>'
    };
});

function ControllerZero($scope, sharedService) {
    $scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function() {
        console.log('handle event');
        $scope.message = sharedService.message;
    });
}

function ControllerOne($scope, sharedService) {
    $scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function() {
        $scope.message = 'ONE: ' + sharedService.message;
    });
}

function ControllerTwo($scope, sharedService) {
    $scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function() {
        $scope.message = 'TWO: ' + sharedService.message;
    });
}



ControllerZero.$inject = ['$scope', 'mySharedService'];

ControllerOne.$inject = ['$scope', 'mySharedService'];

ControllerTwo.$inject = ['$scope', 'mySharedService'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`angular.injector()` creates a new injector, and with it a new `$rootScope`. The event will be broadcasted on this new `$rootScope` instead of on the one your controllers are listening on.

You need to retrieve the injector already associated with your application:

```
angular.element(domElement).injector();
```

You also need to manually trigger the digest loop for the data bindings to update, for example by using `$apply`.

Example:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {

  var element = angular.element(document.querySelector('.ng-scope'));
  var injector = element.injector();
  var scope = element.scope();

  scope.$apply(function() {
    injector.get('mySharedService').prepForBroadcast('hello');
  });
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/NDKBdzSmvN1xY7alafir?p=preview

Comment: Thanx for your reply but I didn't get hello word display on html page.
Please reply me how to display parameter value on html page

Comment: My bad, forgot about the data bindings. Updated my answer.

Comment: As per your given solution I am using following code:
scope.$apply(function() {
    injector.get('mySharedService').prepForBroadcast('hello');
    injector.get('mySharedService').initJSCode();
  });
After completion of prepForBroadcast method I want to initialize another javascript code then how to do that? 
According to above code my initJSCode() is executing earlier then my prepForBroadcast() method is running, but I want to execute initJSCode() when my prepForBroadcast() method execution complete

Comment: Do you just need to wait until after prepForBroadcast has executed, or do you need to wait until everyone that listens for the broadcast to complete as well? Cause there is a big difference between the two scenarios.

Comment: I want to wait until everyone that listens for the broadcast to complete.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it seems you need to do some refactoring. There is no good way to know that. The broadcaster shouldn't really need to know about the listeners or when they are done.

Comment: Ok
Suppose I add above two injector in two different scope.$apply() then this approach is good or not.

Comment: please reply me on above comment

Comment: That wouldn't really change anything.

Comment: I have tried and its working but only I want suggestion from you that this approach is good or not

Answer (score 0):

Another way of publishing events from one controller and listening them in other controllers would be to use [angular-PubSub](https://github.com/georapbox/angular-PubSub) module.

The `PubSub` makes only subscribers to listen to the published events unlike the `$rootScope.$broadcast` in which it sends event to all the Scopes in Scope hierarchy making it inefficient as compared to the PubSub approach.